# White page appearing during BASE Installation for SNORT 2.9.17.1

Tags: apache2, php7, configure, snort

I am installing SNORT 2.9.17.1 using a mannual SNORT-IPS-Tutorial (https://snort-org-site.s3.amazonaws.com/production/document_files/files/000/000/069/original/Snort-IPS-Tutorial.pdf?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIXACIED2SPMSC7GA%2F20210508%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20210508T185038Z&X-Amz-Expires=172800&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=58afb0df6b139671602d04a1ce53352d11bb70200590d66806545700e0e771b9). a problem occurs when i am moving towards BASE Installation Setup . In BASE installation setup i have completed following all commands succesfully.

**1- Configure Apache & PHP**

- sudo cp /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled
- sudo gedit /etc/php/7.4/apache2/php.ini
- Line #452: change to: error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
- a2enmod ssl
- sudo pear config-set preferred_state alpha
- sudo pear channel-update pear.php.net
- sudo pear install --alldeps Image_Color2 Image_Canvas Image_Graph
- /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

**2. Install BASE**

- cd /usr/src
- sudo wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/secureideas/files/BASE/base-1.4.5/base-1.4.5.tar.gz
- sudo tar xzf base-1.4.5.tar.gz
- sudo cp -r base-1.4.5 /var/www/base
- sudo chmod 777 -R /var/www/base

When i am moving towards step 3 in this section, the first task is following:

**3. Configure Base**

- Open the Browser console: https:///base

when i am entering http://192.168.10.15/base to a firefox browser of Ubuntu-20.04.1, a white page appering. I can able to move forward towards other tasks.
​
can anyone guide me please?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of concerns regarding the installation process you followed, as it seems ... haphazard.

Despite the fact it "worked" for you, let's try this one next time:

#### Step 1 — Configure Apache & PHP

1. Enable the default SSL Configuration file:

   ```
   sudo a2ensite /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf
   ```
2. Enable the Apache SSL module:

   ```
   sudo a2enmod ssl
   ```
3. Configure and install the requisite PEAR modules:

   ```
   sudo pear config-set preferred_state alpha
   sudo pear channel-update pear.php.net
   sudo pear install --alldeps Image_Color2 Image_Canvas Image_Graph
   ```
4. Restart Apache:

   ```
   sudo service apache2 restart
   ```

Notes:

- Do not simply copy configuration files from `sites-available` to `sites-enabled`. That's not how this stuff is supposed to work.
- Do not modify your global `php.ini` file to change the `error_reporting` variable. This can be done in the project's primary configuration `.php` file for better isolation.
- Try to use the `sudo service {name} restart` method when working with system services.

#### Step 2 — Install BASE

1. Make sure you are in a scratch directory, such as `~/Downloads` or `~/tmp` or some such:

   ```
   cd ~/tmp
   ```
2. Download the source package:

   ```
   sudo wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/secureideas/files/BASE/base-1.4.5/base-1.4.5.tar.gz
   ```
3. Expand the package:

   ```
   sudo tar xzf base-1.4.5.tar.gz
   ```
4. Move the source files to their Apache-ownable location:

   ```
   sudo mv base-1.4.5 /var/www/base
   ```
5. Set ownership and *functional* permissions:

   ```
   sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/base
   sudo chmod 755 -R /var/www/base
   ```

Notes:

- Do not save random things from the Internet in `/usr/src`. There's no need.
- Apache will refuse to work with directories that are `777` because it's not at all secure ... which raises the question of why you're trying to use SSL if the files are `777` ... which raises another question of why you want to use BASE (Basic Analysis and Security Engine), as this Apache installation would immediately fail its own tests.

#### Step 3 — Configure BASE

This step is going to be *very* different from what you wrote, because:

- you have not configured your SSL certificates
- it would be better to configure Apache to look at `/var/www/base`
- the BASE source files have not been updated since June of 2013

So ... let's get started:

#### Step 3.1 — Configure Apache again

1. Change to the `sites-enabled` directory:

   ```
   cd /etc/apache/sites-enabled`
   ```
2. Remove the file you copied

   ```
   sudo rm -f default-ssl.conf
   ```
3. Check to see if you have any other files in the directory and, if so, *disable* them. For example:

   ```
   sudo a2dissite 000-default.conf
   ```
4. Change to the `sites-available` directory and copy the `default-ssl.conf` file to something you can customise:

   ```
   cd ../sites-available`
   sudo cp default-ssl.conf 001-base-ssl.conf
   ```
5. Edit the new file:

   ```
   sudo vi 001-base-ssl.conf
   ```
6. Change the `DocumentRoot`, `SSLCertificateFile`, `SSLCertificateKeyFile`, and any other settings to their proper values:

   ```
   DocumentRoot /var/www/base
   ...
   ```
7. Save the file, enable the site, and restart Apache:

   ```
   sudo a2ensite 001-base-ssl.conf
   sudo service apache2 restart
   ```

#### Step 3.2 — Update the BASE source code for PHP 7.x

This I cannot (and will not) walk you through. As already mentioned, the last update to BASE was 8 years ago. The source files are most likely using a bunch of deprecated functions and features that need to be updated for PHP 7.x and beyond. You will need to identify the parts of the system that are broken and fix them.

#### Step 3.3 — Configure Base

Now, after what has probably been a lot more work than you anticipated, you can configure BASE.

1. Open `https://{IP / Domain}` in your browser of choice
2. Carry on with the installation process

Notes:

- Note the `s` in the protocol. If you are using SSL, this is important.